# Why am I not receiving any response from my PHP page and no other errors?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have 2 pages, practice.php and addtocart.php. In practice.php, I gather info from a form and send the info using AJAX to addtocart.php. This page then connects to the database and inserts my values. However I am not receiving any response from addtocart.php and no data is being inserted in the database.

I have been trying to figure out the problem but cannot seem to find it. Please help.

practice.php

```
   //form from which addtocart is being called
     <form id="mehendicones">
      Color: <input list="mehendi_color" class="mehendi_color" 
         id="mehendi_color1">
                <datalist id="mehendi_color">
                    <option value="Black">
                    <option value="White">
                    <option value="Brown">
                    <option value="Dark Red"> 
                </datalist>
                    <br>
                <p id="price">17</p>
        Quantity<input type="number" min="5" max="15" 
             id="quantity_mehendi_color" step="1">

        <input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" style="text-align:center;" 
           onclick="addtocart()" >

            </form>

function addtocart() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "addtocart.php";
  request.open("POST", url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form- 
      urlencoded");
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      alert(request.response);
    }
  };
  var pdetails = "mehendi cones";
  var pquantity = document.forms["mehendicones"] 
  ["quantity_mehendi_color"].value;
  var pcolor = document.forms["mehendicones"] 
  ["mehendi_color1"].value;
  var price = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;

  var data = ({
    "pdetails": pdetails, 
    "pquantity": pquantity, 
    "pcolor": pcolor, 
    "price": price
  });

  request.send(data);
}
```

addtocart.php

```
<?php
  include 'includes/database.php';

  // Handling data in JSON format on the server-side using PHP
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        // build a PHP variable from JSON sent using POST 
                     //method
        if($_POST){
$v= json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")));
        echo json_encode($v);
        $v->pdetails;
        $v->pcolor;
        $v->pquantity;
        $v->price;
               $fname=$_SESSION['firstname'];
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
                  $nam=$fname.$id;

             $sql="INSERT INTO ".$nam." 
         (userid,pdetails,price,pquantity,pcolor) VALUES 
             ('$id','$pdetails','$price','$pquantity','$pcolor');";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "added to cart";
        }else{
            echo "couldnot add to cart..try again";
        }
    }

            mysqli_close($con);


              ?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes and it didnot say anything at all..it was blank

Comment: That means that the request isn't being sent. How are you calling `addtocart()`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in the request.open..the url is addtocart.php

Comment: is your db connect credentials correct?

Comment: @Vishwa yes i have used the  'includes/database.php' in other pages connecting to the same database and it is good

Comment: You have to call the function. Add addtocart() at the end of addtocart file.

Comment: @TasneemEdoo that's not what I mean. I can see the AJAX call logic, but if there is no traffic in the console then the request isn't being made. The most likely cause for this is that your `addtocart()` function is not being called, so where are you calling it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have edited the question and added the form from which the function addtocart recieves the details

Comment: try this: `<form onsubmit="addtocart(); return false;">` the `return false;` is important and will prevent classic post beeing made

Comment: @Kazz  tried it still no response

Comment: do you have any erros in console which stops function execution ?

Comment: @Kazz the console is blank even on the network section it shows no data being recieved or sent

Comment: i have tried your code with `onsubmit="return false;"` and the ajax post has been made so i have no idea why it don't work for you, but the code work

Comment: @TasneemEdoo in your php you have f($_POST) , try with if(isset($_POST["data"]) and also change  var data = ({
    "pdetails": pdetails, 
    "pquantity": pquantity, 
    "pcolor": pcolor, 
    "price": price
  }); for  var data = {
 "data": [{
  "pdetails": pdetails,
  "pquantity": pquantity,
  "pcolor": pcolor,
  "price": price
 }]
}; hope it helps

Comment: @stanchacon ...thank you i will try it!!